# Set the duration of each frame in a video using Xuggler

Tags: java, video, xuggler

How to set the duration of each frame in a video using Xuggler?

I want to create a video through my Java application using Xuggler.  What I want is really simple.  I have some JPG files and I want to encode them into a video.  I've done that using some helpful sample code.  My question is how can I set the duration of each frame?

For example if I want each picture to be projected for 10secs. I'll post below the sample code of what I have actually done so far.

```
        for (int index = 0; index < filenames.size(); index++) {
          if(filenames.get(index).toString().contains("jpg")){
            System.err.println(filenames.get(index).toString());

            // take the screen shot
//            BufferedImage screen = getDesktopScreenshot();
            BufferedImage screen = ImageIO.read(filenames.get(index));

            // convert to the right image type
            BufferedImage bgrScreen = convertToType(screen,BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

            int i=0;
            while(i<FRAME_RATE){
                writer.encodeVideo(0, bgrScreen, System.nanoTime() - startTime, 
                   TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                ++i;
            }

            // sleep for frame rate milliseconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / FRAME_RATE));
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A single blank line of white space is always enough.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want(Set the duration of each frame in a video using Xuggler)  is really simple

No it isn't. It's just simple to describe. No video format I know of supports different durations for each frame.

> For example if I want each picture to be projected for 10secs

But that is not the same thing as 'setting the duration of **each** frame'.  Some video formats allow very low frame rates (I think, not sure).  Failing that, add each image as many times as needed to fill the required '10 seconds'.

Comment: ok,that's what i've done so far but i thought it was another way.If that's correct then no problem.Thx